# Is it possible to regenerate java source from XML files in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to setup hot-swap with DCEVM for a Hybris project. This works fine for java files.

Now I would like to be able to rebuild Java sources from the facades beans .xml files without having to run `ant clean all`.

Is there a quicker way ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the tool you mentioned, but to generate the beans running "ant build" is sufficient and it is much faster than "ant clean all".

Comment: Not if you rename or delete existing attributes/beans.